# Render pages using switch statement in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, next.js

I have developed a static website (except blog page) and added [slug].js file in a nested folder. Inside the [slug].js I have used the Router function to get the route and used it in a switch statement to return page content.
Because of SEO issues, I want server-side render but don't know that with switch statement render would be server-side or client-side.
First, is using switch statement a correct way for routing and returning content?
Second, will it render as a server-side or client-side?